# z-index not rendering as expected with before pseudo-element

Tags: css, z-index

Why isn't `#para1` rendering **above** `#para1:before`?

**[CODEPEN HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYjGrG)**

```css
.para {
  color: #fafafa;
}
#para1 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#para1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 150px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 500px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}
#para1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="para1" class="para"><span class="hpro">HELLO <span class="bold">WORLD</span> </span> <span class="satisfy">pre launch contest festival</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you want this output http://jsfiddle.net/6yox39vx/

Comment: or this http://jsfiddle.net/6yox39vx/1/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes the second one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `#para` is establishing a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) itself.

Try removing its `z-index` and give a negative `z-index` to its pseudo *child* element `#para:before` as follows:

```css
.para {
  color: #fafafa;
}
#para1 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}
#para1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 150px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 500px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
#para1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="para1" class="para"><span class="hpro">HELLO <span class="bold">WORLD</span> </span> <span class="satisfy">pre launch contest festival</span>
</div>
```